# SQL Server If Null Return Everything

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out this stored procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetTotals]

@Service nvarchar(50),
@Country nvarchar(50)  = NULL,
@Region nvarchar(50) = NULL

as 

SELECT
  CASE @Service
    WHEN 'Army' THEN Sum(Army)
    WHEN 'Navy' THEN Sum(Navy)
    When 'Marine_Corps' then Sum(Marine_Corps)
    When 'Air_Force' then Sum(Air_Force)
    ELSE NULL
  END      as "ServiceTotal"

FROM
  All_Records

WHERE Country = CASE WHEN @Country IS NOT NULL THEN @Country ELSE Country END
  AND Region = CASE WHEN @Region IS NOT NULL THEN @Region ELSE Region END
```

What I want is if `@Country` is not null, then return records `where Country = @Country`, Else returns all countries. I want the same behavior for `Region`.

I have tried Else Is Not Null, and Else !=Null, and Else <> Null

But nothing is working.

Edit:

I figured it out. I just wasn't calling the procedure correctly. It is working. I have to call the procedure, named GetTotals like this:

- GetTotals Navy, Null, Europe  This would return total Navy for all of europe.
- GetTotals Navy, Albania, Null  This would return totals for Navy in Albania

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often done like this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(@Country,Country) = Country AND COALESCE(@Region,Region) = Region
```

Comment: Also in SQL Server `ISNULL()` is an alternative ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (Country = @Country OR @Country IS NULL) AND (Region = @Region OR @Region IS NULL)
```